# unresolved identifier received when trying to return an array in function

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I receive an error: "use of unresolved identifier 'data' when trying to return the data array. My code is listed below. Can someone advise why this is occurring?

```
    public func loadData()->[Q] {
    let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let pred = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "question", predicate: pred)
    publicData.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: ({results, error in
        if(error != nil) {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if results!.count > 0 {
                var data = [Q]()
                for result in results!{
                    let quest = result.object(forKey: "question_name") as! String!
                    let a = result.object(forKey: "a") as! String!
                    let b = result.object(forKey: "b") as! String!
                    let c = result.object(forKey: "c") as! String!
                    let d = result.object(forKey: "d") as! String!
                    let answer = result.object(forKey: "answer") as! String!
                    let category = result.object(forKey: "category") as! String!
                    let final = Q(quest: quest!, A:a!, B: b!, C: c!, D: d!, answer: answer!, category: category!)
                    data.append(final)
                }
            }
        }
    }))
    return data
}
```

Comment: Look at where `data` is declared. Look at where you get the error. Variables have scope. They don't exist outside of that scope.

Comment: Resolved or unresolved, you can't return anything form a function including an asynchronous task.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can see that the declaration is within the completion block. Can you suggest how I can make use of the results of the query outside of the function? I do not need to display anything in the UI. I just need to make use of the results.

Comment: I was actually able to return the data with a sleep(3) step (after importing the Darwin library). This was done at the step immediately previous to the 'return data' step. Not ideal but this does show that I can return from an async task

Comment: `sleep` is extremely unreliable. You cannot guarantee that the asynchronous task is completed before the end of the sleep. That's why you practically *can't return anything form a function including an asynchronous task*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No!, no!, no!,  **NEVER EVER** use `sleep` to work around an asynchronous task !! That's horrendous.

- For convenience create an enum with `success` and `failure` cases and associated types

  ```
  enum Result {
    case success([Q]), failure(Error)
  }
  ```
- In `loadData` return `data` or the `error` in the completion handler. I removed a bunch of redundant parentheses, exclamation marks and the empty check of the array. In case of no error and no matching data an empty array of `Q` is returned.

  ```
  public func loadData(completion: @escaping (Result)->() ) {
    let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let pred = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "question", predicate: pred)
    publicData.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {results, error in
      if error != nil {
       completion(.failure(error!))
      } else {
        var data = [Q]()
        for result in results! {
          let quest = result.object(forKey: "question_name") as! String
          let a = result.object(forKey: "a") as! String
          let b = result.object(forKey: "b") as! String
          let c = result.object(forKey: "c") as! String
          let d = result.object(forKey: "d") as! String
          let answer = result.object(forKey: "answer") as! String
          let category = result.object(forKey: "category") as! String
          let final = Q(quest: quest, A:a, B: b, C: c, D: d, answer: answer, category: category)
          data.append(final)
        }
        completion(.success(data))
      }
    })
  }
  ```
- Call the function

  ```
  loadData { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let data): print(data) // do something with the result
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you will keep your hands off `sleep` when dealing with asynchronous tasks.